# Using recursion to find the longest string in a sentence (Array.prototype.splice() method )

Tags: javascript, recursion

In order to return the length of the longest word in the provided sentence.
My attempt:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {

var arr = str.split(" ");

function re(arr) {

if (arr[0].length >= arr[1].length) {arr.splice(1,1); return re(arr);}

/*if the first element's length is larger than the second element's length, 
splice the smaller element, then call its own function re(arr) using the 
array with the second element being spliced, which to my understanding 
is calling 
re(["Theeeee","brown","fox","jumped","over","the","lazy","dog"])*/

else if (arr[0].length < arr[1].length) {arr.splice(0,1); return re(arr);}

} 

return arr[0].length;

findLongestWord("Theeeee quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Regarding the comment after the first if statement, did I misunderstood any aspect about how recursion works?

Code that works using For loop:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {

var arr = str.split(" ");

for (i = arr.length; i > 1 ;i--) {

if (arr[0].length >= arr[1].length) {arr.splice(1,1);}

else if (arr[0].length < arr[1].length) {arr.splice(0,1);}

} 

return arr[0].length;

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: What does the code do? Does it work as expected? If not, what input are you passing in, and what are you getting back? Also, your code formatting is messed up. This code will cause syntax errors. Use proper formatting and line breaks. There's no reason to compress the code so much. Use one  statement per line.

Comment: Hello Christopher, thanks for the advice, I'll dig deeper regarding the formatting issue later on. For now, I want to get the length of the longest word within a sentence , and the first code is not passing the challenge of FreeCodeCamp while my attempt using for loops did the trick, I am confused about the first piece of code regarding the way i call back re(arr), did I miss something? the code keep giving me the length of the first element of  the sentence array, why isn't it performing the steps I commented in the code after the first if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) instead of recursion. Btw, you should apply Christopher recomendations. I have formatted your code and it works properly for me. Only one missing bracket.

```js
let str = 'Some random words';

let result = str.split(' ').reduce(function(ret, el) {
  return el.length > ret ? el.length : ret;
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Your code has two mistakes, you were not controlling the case your array had only one item and you were not calling the function `re` at all.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ");
  function re(arr) {
    if(arr.length === 1) return arr;
    if (arr[0].length >= arr[1].length) {
      arr.splice(1,1); 
      return re(arr);
    } else if (arr[0].length < arr[1].length) {
      arr.splice(0,1); 
      return re(arr);
    }
  } 
  re(arr);
  return arr[0].length;
}

let res = findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hello Diego thanks for the suggestion, for the sake of practice, I would like to know what adjustment are there to be made in order for the first code to work? did I missed anything crucial whilst calling back the re(arr) function itself after the first if statement's splicing ? The code kept giving me the length of the first element of the string array regardless of the if statements in the code.

Comment: @ShinraLow Here you are! Any doubt just ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally know where I messed up, I'd been so used to the return statement as the default beginning of every FCC challenge that I assumed a every function will "auto-return" everything that are being processed, like a For or While loop. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Math.max to get the desired result. No recursion needed.

```js
let sentence = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

function longestWord(s) {
  return Math.max(...s.split(" ").map(v => v.length));
}

console.log(longestWord(sentence))
```

Comment: Hello baao thanks for the suggestion, for the sake of practice, I would like to know what adjustment are there to be made in order for the first code to work? did I missed anything crucial whilst calling back the re(arr) function itself after the first if statement's splicing ? The code kept giving me the length of the first element of the string array regardless of the if statements in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion means that you call the same function from its body until some condition is fulfilled.

Your code can be rewritten this way:

```
function findLongestWord(sentence, word) {
  var wordsList = sentence.split(" ");
  var lastWord = wordsList.pop();
  var longestWord = lastWord.length > word.length ? lastWord : word;
  if (sentence.length > 0) {
    var newSentence = wordsList.join(" ");
    return findLongestWord(newSentence, longestWord);
  } else {
    return longestWord;
  }
};

var longestWord = findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", '');
console.log(longestWord);
```

There are many ways you can check condition. In many cases you will  variable called accumulator. Here I used just sentece passed as argument. I check if there are any words (after splitting it to words table). If there are no words I return final result. I hope my example will make this subject clearer for you.

Comment: Hello KamilD thanks for the suggestion, for the sake of practice, I would like to know what adjustment are there to be made in order for the first code to work? did I missed anything crucial whilst calling back the re(arr) function itself after the first if statement's splicing ? The code kept giving me the length of the first element of the string array regardless of the if statements in the code.